# Finding nodes that have all common intermediaries

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm creating a system in which we match `orders` to `staff`. Conceptually, an `order` is a request for person to do some work, and a `staff` is a person who can do that work. An `order` can have one or more `requirements` (i.e. restrictions on who can do the work), and a `staff` can have one more more `requirements` (i.e. qualifications to do work).

I'm attempting to create a cypher query that will give me all `staff` that have *all* of the `requirement`s listed by a given `order`. Said another way, I'm trying to find all `staff` nodes that are related to every `requirement` node that is related to a given `order` node. **My question is**: how do I create a cypher query to model that business logic?

As an example, consider the following sample data:

- [A picture view of my sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dIzO.jpg)
- Alternatively, here is [an
  interactive console for my data](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=ukzlme)

Look at the *orderId: 1* node. it has a `requires` relationship to two nodes, labeled *RN* and *ER IV*. In order words, order #1 requires any applicants to have the RN qualification and the ER IV qualification. It so happens that staff member *Evan* (*staffId: 1*) has both of those qualifications, so he should be able to apply for that job. The staff member *Tim* has ONE of those requirements, but not both, so he should not be able to apply for that job. Additionally, *orderId: 2* only has one requirement, which Evan and Tim both have, so they should both be able to apply for that job.

So in essence, if I were to start with order #1 I would want to get back only Evan. If I were to start with order #2 I would want to get back Evan and Tim*.

The following query is half way there. It will give me all unique paths from a given order to a staff member one requirement at a time. However, it does not check that EVERY requirement path is satisfied (which means currently it will only work for orders that only have a single requirement):

```
start o=node(2) 
match o-[:requires]->req<-[:hasRequirement]-s 
return o, req, s;
```

So what are my options? Can I somehow check the presence of an unknown number of matching relationships? Or will I need to model my data a different way?

***Edit:** I made a mistake when setting up my sample data. *Tim* should have been associated with *RN* so that he qualified for order #2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess this cypher statement solves your problem:

```
start o=node(2) 
match o-[:requires]->req<-[:hasRequirement]-p 
with o, p, count(req) as c 
where length(o-[:requires]-()) = c 
return p, c
```

Answer (score 3):

I came up with

```
start o=node(2) 
match o-[orderReqRel:requires]->r 
with count(orderReqRel) as orderReqs, o 
match p-[personReqRel:hasRequirement]->r<-[:requires]-o 
with count(personReqRel) as personReqs,p,orderReqs 
where personReqs=orderReqs
return p;
```

Seems to work for Order 1 where I get back only Evan.
Order 2 doesn't seem to have a requirement that Tim has (your explanation indicates that but for some reason, not seeing it in the console you shared)

Comment: Good catch, I made a mistake when setting up my sample data. In any case, your answer works perfectly, as does Stefan's -- I wish I could accept both of your answers. I'm going to pick Stefan's answer just because it's a bit more concise, but thank you for answering as well.

Comment: Stefan's is much better :-)