# Neo4j : Find children derived from same parents in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How Can we do this in cypher? 
There are **n parents p1, p2, p3.... pn** and **m children c1, c2,c3... cm**.
Suppose **c1** is derived from (child of) **p1,p2 and p3** and also **c2** is derived from (child of) **p1, p2 and p3**. 
Given **c1** can we find **c2**? (node derived from the same parents as c1) 
A child can have 1...n parents.

Comment: Do they need to have the EXACT same parents, or can it be an overlap? That is, if c1 derives from p1,p2,p3,and p4, and c2 derives from p1,p2,p3, do you want to find them?

Comment: We need to find the nodes derived from the exact same set of parents.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I actually asked [an extremely similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657265/finding-nodes-that-have-all-common-intermediaries) here a few weeks ago, and the answer I got then will work for you too with just a bit of tweaking.

```
START c1=node(*), c2=node(*)
MATCH c1-[:ChildOf]->parent<-[:ChildOf]-c2 
WITH c1, c2, count(parent) AS parentsFound
WHERE length(c1-[:ChildOf]->()) = parentsFound
  AND length(c2-[:ChildOf]->()) = parentsFound
  AND c1 <> c2
RETURN c1, c2
```

*Note: presumably you will have a better way of picking your `c1` and `c2` than using `node(*)`.*

The logic of this query line by line:

1. Starting with all children `c1` and `c2`,
2. Find all `parent`s shared by `c1` and `c2`
3. Count the number of shared `parent`s that were found
4. Make sure that the number of `parent`s found matches the total number of `parent`s that `c1` has.
5. Make sure that the number of `parent`s found matches the total number of `parent`s that `c2` has.
6. (OPTIONAL) Don't bother comparing nodes to themselves
7. Return the results!

Comment: +1. I don't think you even need to do both where clauses--just checking the length of `c1-[:ChildOf]->()` should be sufficient, right?

Comment: @WesFreeman Not necessarily. If c2 has MORE parents than just those shared with c1 then c2 won't be properly excluded without the second clause. If the OP doesn't care if c2 has more parents then that clause can be removed.