# Cypher query that matches all paths

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph with nodes like "project", "employee" and "technology". There are relations between project and technology and between employee and technology.

I want to find employees that know all the technology used by a project. My cyper-query looks like this:

```
start project=node:project(name = "Project1") 
match technology <-[:USED]- project , employee -[:KNOWS]-> technology 
return employee
```

When running this query I get all employees that know one technology used by the project, and want employees that know all technologies used by the project. Is this possible in cypher?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
start project=node:project(name = "Project1") 
match employee -[:KNOWS]-> technology <-[:USED]- project 
with count(technology) as knownTech, employee, project
where length(()<-[:USED]-project)=knownTech
return employee
```

See [Finding nodes that have all common intermediaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657265/finding-nodes-that-have-all-common-intermediaries/14662744#14662744)

Comment: Great, thanks! There's an extra parenthese after project in the where clause though. Other than that, great! Btw, had to upgrade neoclipse in order to use with and where, I had a version from 2012.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use this to avoid computing the number of technologies used by the project per employee:

```
start project=node:project(name = "Project1") 
match technology <-[:USED]- project 
with count(technology) as projectTech, project
match employee -[:KNOWS]-> technology <-[:USED]- project 
with count(technology) as knownTech, projectTech, employee
where projectTech=knownTech
return employee
```

Comment: That makes sense, didn't think of it. I re-wrote some of my queries after http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657265/finding-nodes-that-have-all-common-intermediaries/14662744#14662744 but now I see that this one is more efficient, thanks